# Scroll View is not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, scroll

I have designed my app for 4inch devices using xcode 5 and storyboard builder. Since the 3.5inch screen is a little bit smaller, I want to make my view scrollable.

This is what I have done: I added a ScrollView using interface builder and added my View (that contains all elements) as a subview of it.

[image]

I start the app using the 4inch simulator and it does not scroll - exactly what I want. But when I open it with the 3.5inch simulator my content gets cut and scrolling is not possible. Why? And how can I activate it?

Comment: google - uiscrollview tutorial ios 7

Answer (score 0):

have you implement the **UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol**

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Autolayout?

You also want to make sure your scrollview's contentSize is set to your view's size.